# wordpress thumbnail pictures not showing

Tags: image, wordpress

hi i uploaded some pictures to my wordpress site the wierd thing is that its uploaded correctly the pictures are showing inside the post but outside the post i get an broken image pictogram. can anyone help me with this problem ?

http://www.telefoonhandleiding.com/

Comment: go your ftp theme and change cache folder permission.

Answer (score 1):

something is wrong with timthumb.php:

If you open the Image in a Browser, you will see what it actually returns: http://www.telefoonhandleiding.com/wp-content/themes/liomagazine/scripts/timthumb.php?src=http://www.telefoonhandleiding.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Samsung-Galaxy-Ace-Handleiding-telefoon.jpg&w=200&h=150&zc=1

Answer (score 0):

do you mean that the pictures aren't showing up in the blog excerpt page? or they aren't showing in your wordpress media section? or where?  If it's in the blog excerpt page it would definitley be something with your theme that your using.

Comment: they show in post/and admin . 
check the site i posted.

but on the main homepage (last posts) its showing broken pictures